# How to insert any table's column name in another table as record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 50 columns. I want to insert all the column names into another table as record. How to do this?

I am trying this, but it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO fields(field)
    select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where table_name='data'
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/277865).  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem with your query is that you are trying to insert all the columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` into a single column in `Field` (field) - The number of columns you are selecting and the number of columns you are inserting to must match.  - `INSERT INTO fields(field) SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'data'`. You also say *"a record"*, rather than *"records"*, which would imply you want one row, so you may need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to create a single delimited string of your column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want the `column_name` so only choose that:

```
INSERT INTO fields(field)
     select COLUMN_NAME
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     where table_name = 'data';
```

Your query should generate an error, because you have too many columns in the `select`.